How and why does Python's built-in round() function work flawlessly with pandas?
I have difficulty in understanding the following behavior of Python's built-in round function:
round doesn't work with lists:
round([1.345, 2.718], 2) # Raises TypeError

round doesn't work with numpy arrays:
import numpy as np
round(np.array([1.345, 2.718]), 2) # Raises TypeError

However, you can use round smoothly with pandas as seen below.
import pandas as pd
round(pd.Series([1.345, 2.718]), 2) # Works just fine

Is this some kind of overloading or special handling due to the "courtesy" of pandas?

"For a general Python object number, round delegates to number.__round__" - presumably pd.Series implements it but np.array doesn't.

Pandas Series objects implement the __round__ method, which gets called first in CPython.
